# Не импортируется библиотека turtle

Tags: python, библиотеки, рисование, turtle

Простите, как вызывать библиотеку turtle

```
import turtle # Так у меня не импортируется(
```

```
from turtle import * # Так тоже...
```

Что это за заколдованный круг? Или как это вообще вызывать?
Ошибки не должно быть...

Comment: потому что не надо называть собственный файлы именами модулей, который в них используются

Comment: что должно вызываться? вы ничего не вызываете, а лишь импортируете

Comment: Что пишет, какая ошибка, почему вы решили, что не импортируется?

Comment: не обнаружены функиции типо того...

Comment: Текст ошибки добавьте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала переименуйте ваш файл, если он называется `turtle.py` на любое другое адекватное название, далее напишите для примера:

```
import turtle        
print(0)
```

Если выдаст ответ: `0` - всё работает. Других видимых проблем не существует, `turtle` не требует установки, так же при запуске файла, интерпретатор Python-а выдает ошибку, в следующий раз скопируйте ошибку и вставьте в конце, чтобы Вам могли помочь с проблемой.